# Prevent iOS QuickLook from generating a cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, quicklook

I'm using the [QuickLook Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html) in my iOS app to preview various files. I recently noticed that QuickLook is keeping a cache of all previewed files in my app's `tmp` directory. There are two issues with QuickLook caching files though:

1. These cached files are already stored in the Documents directory. So in theory the app could double in size if the user wants to preview all of their files (which they probably will). Okay, no big deal, I can periodically clean out the cache using this code:

   ```
   NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:nil];
    for (NSString *filename in fileArray)  {
       [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
   }
   ```
2. The second, and **most important issue** is that QuickLook seems to be creating a secondary cache in a system folder (not my app). This is an issue because users have the option to encrypt individual files in my app. If they preview a file before encrypting, it looks normal. If they encrypt and then preview afterwards, the file still appears as if it was not encrypted. I know there is not a problem with the encryption because the encrypted file stored in my app's `Documents` directory is encrypted and can't be read (properly) by any program. This is a major issue, as it may cause the user to believe the file was not encrypted. It is also a security issue because it means that QuickLook is caching the file elsewhere.

Here is my QuickLook code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return 1;
 }

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //Get the stored user data and file name
    NSString *FileName = [defaults objectForKey:@"FileName"]; //Name of file stored in NSUserDefaults
    NSString *finalFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileName];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalFilePath];
}

- (IBAction)previewFile:(id)sender {
   //Setup QuickLook
   QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
   previewController.delegate=self;
   previewController.dataSource=self;
   previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
   [previewController reloadData];
   [self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
   [previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
}
```

Does anyone know where the QuickLook cache is, or if there is one (maybe it's some kind of bug)?

**How can I prevent QuickLook from caching files, or how can I reset the cache?** If neither of these are possible is there an iOS 6 alternative to QuickLook (I've heard QuickLook was changed in iOS 6 so there aren't any workarounds, alternatives, etc.)?

Any solutions or ideas appreciated!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you other than "I didn't see a way either and used a `UIWebView`" (despite the worse functionality). Have you tried submitting a feature request to Apple and seeing what they said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a way to prevent QLPreviewController from doing it's own caching, you might want to consider making your own version QLPreviewController with a UIWebView (since thats capable of viewing many file types such as PDF, docs, xls, etc.).

It's by no means an ideal solution and you won't have anywhere near the level of performance/UI quality as the QLPreviewController will provide.  Yeah... it's a bit of a hacked solution, but short of a public API to clear the secondary cache... it's the only thing I can think of.

I guess it's a toss up between user friendliness + security.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can reset the entire cache from the command prompt using:

```
qlmanage -r cache
```

Or generate a preview for specific documents using:

```
qlmanage -p document.ext
```

But because this is a command line solution, this is probably not what you need. Good luck, though.

Comment: I'm guessing that would work on OSX, but probably not on iOS - since there isn't any access to the command line :-(

Comment: A very good point. I wonder why I thought the OP was using OSX. Leaving this answer in in case others have issues with QuickLook in OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try an NSURLCache and see if that helps.

Set it up in application didfinishlaunchingwithoptions:

```
int cacheSizeMemory = 8*1024*1024; // 8MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 16*1024*1024; // 16MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory   diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Then you can do the following when you want to empty the cache

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Whether or not this works with quick look I don't know but it's worth a try.